# Issue with clicks passing through one sibling in a LinearLayout but not through the other

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout

I have two `TextView`s in a horizontal `LinearLayout` that is contained within another container that is clickable -- `android:clickable="true"`. I don't want clicks to pass through either of the `LinearLayout`'s children, but they're passing through one of them.

The two `TextView` children are nearly identical except for their id, weight, and gravity attributes; however, I tried setting everything equal except for the ids but clicks still passed through one of the siblings.

Programatically, nothing happens to one that doesn't happens to the other. It's the strangest thing.

Here is the code for the `LinearLayout`:

*the clicks are bleeding through `@id/sibling_2`

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_container"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/maring_left"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/maring_right"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bg">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sibling_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="30"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
                android:hint="Score"/>

            <!--the text view that clicks are bleeding through-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sibling_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
                android:hint="100%"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show your java code

Comment: @VenomVendor not sure if you saw the update, but i deleted it because i brought up points that were not true. in case you did see it, `interim_container` still registers clicks even if i don't null its background

Comment: @VenomVendor and as far as java code goes, there isn't any besides finding the views by their id and then setting their text

Comment: @VenomVendor i take that back. i add an `onClickListener` to `sibling_1` -- the sibling that doesn't let clicks bleed through it

Answer (score 0):

I modified your layout. Maybe this can work for you:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_container"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/maring_left"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/maring_right"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_margin"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:background="@drawable/bg">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sibling_1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
                android:hint="Score"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sibling_2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
                android:hint="100%"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: well both `TextView`s could potentially get clicked. the problem is that when `@id/sibling_2 ` is clicked, the click event that's meant for `@id/super_container` is registered -- check update. when `sibling_1` is clicked, nothing happens, which is what's suppose to happen for both of the `TextView`s